# How to take a field value after dynamic SOQL

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I am trying to get field value from a dynamic SOQL result. Here i have a object where end user need to enter the field name which he need. I am SOQL it like this:

```
UserprofileSOQL = 'SELECT Contact.'+homepgProfile[0].UserProfile_Field__c+',  
                   Contact.Account.'+homepgProfile[0].AccountProfile_Field__c+' 
                   FROM User WHERE id = \''+ userID   +'\'';
```

where `homepgProfile[0].AccountProfile_Field__c` and `homepgProfile[0].UserProfile_Field__c` from an object where the end user enter the filed name.

Now i am trying to get the field value from the query result. I try to get the field value 
as `userProfile = userLst[0].Contact.homepgProfile[0].UserProfile_Field__c`
but i am getting the following error:

> Save error: Invalid field homepgProfile for SObject Contact. MY CODE
>   userProfile =
>   userLst[0].Contact.homepgProfile[0].AccountProfile_Field__c;

Please guide me the proper way to get the solution.

Comment: Could you specify the syntax error and perhaps show the code in a formatted fashion.  It would help to be able to see the code and the error it produces.

Comment: Save error: Invalid field homepgProfile for SObject Contact. MY CODE userProfile = userLst[0].Contact.homepgProfile[0].AccountProfile_Field__c;

Comment: I would be very careful with what you're building, that looks like exposing a lot of security holes. (soql injection)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the get method, but this is not so simple when you need to access relationship fields.

In more details if you have the following SoQL

```
List <MyCustomObject__c> myList = [SELECT id, name, rel__r.Name FROM ....] ;
```

you can access the fields of MyCustomObject__c retrieved using the following notation

```
for (MyCustomObject__c mco:myList)
{
    system.debug('name:' + mco.get('name'));
}
```

However in your case you need to traverse relationships so its a little bit more complex.
You need one more step to retrieve the related object using

```
SObject a = mco.getSObject('rel__c');
```

then you need to do one more step using get method on a.

For more details check this
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_dml.htm

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to access child relationships?? if I assume your userLst var is of a  type, and if you want to access a field that is on a relationship you can do it this way

```
  //From the Parent object
  List<Account> accts = [SELECT Id, Name, Custom_Field__c (SELECT Id, Name, Custom_Field__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account];

  //Accessing to those records
  for(Account a : accts){
      for(Contact c : a.Contacts){

      }
  }

  // From the child object
  SELECT Id From Contact WHERE AccountId in (SELECT Id FROM Account)
```

And you can convert those queries dynamically if you want to, and please share your code so we can better understand your problem